# How to avoid global semaphores and queues when using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

I have a problem with my code. It works, but I cannot avoid using global semaphores. I have 3 thread functions. the first is run by 10 threads. The second and third are run by 2 threads each. These threads should run without having race conditions. In addition, they should communicate with each other. I use a user defined queue class for communications between threads and between the threads and main. Also, I use the semaphores to achieve mutual exclusion between the threads. Since I declare the instance of the queue class and the semaphores in a global manner, I do not have to pass them to any function. They are accessible to any function in this program. However, this is not a healthy way to write programs. Therefore, I ask you, how to declare the queue and the semaphores locally, and what is the best way to pass them between threads.

// queueString header

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;

class queueString
{
public:
    queueString();
    ~queueString();
    void qPush(string str);
    string qPop();
private:
    sem_t queueSem;
    queue <string> q;
};
```

//queueString class

```
#include "queueString.h"

using namespace std;

// queue class that will enqueue and dequeue atomically.
queueString::queueString(){
    sem_init(&queueSem, 0, 1);
}
queueString::~queueString(){}

void queueString::qPush(string str){
    sem_wait(&queueSem);
    this->q.push(str);
    sem_post(&queueSem);
}

string queueString::qPop(){
    sem_wait(&queueSem);
    string str = this->q.front();
    q.pop();
    sem_post(&queueSem);
    return str;
}
```

//The three threads with main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "queueString.h"

using namespace std;

//My question is here, How to declare the variables below locally, and where 
// is the right place to declare them, and how to pass them to threads?

sem_t s12, s13, s21, s31, sthr1, sthr2[2], sthr3[2], printSem;
sem_t idInitializationSemMainToThread, idInitializationSemThreadToMain;
queueString q = queueString();

#define THR1NUM 10
#define THR2NUM 2
#define THR3NUM 2

void printString(string str);

void *thread1(void* arg){
    sem_wait(&idInitializationSemMainToThread);
    int *pnum = (int *)arg;
    int thr_1_ID = *pnum;
    sem_post(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain);
    sem_wait(&sthr1);
    string value= "THR1 ";
    value.append(to_string(thr_1_ID));
    q.qPush(value);
    sem_post(&s12);
    sem_wait(&s21);
    value= "2nd Iteration THR1 ";
    value.append(to_string(thr_1_ID));
    q.qPush(value);
    sem_post(&s13);
    sem_wait(&s31);
    sem_post(&sthr1);

}

void *thread2(void* arg){
    sem_wait(&idInitializationSemMainToThread);
    int *pnum = (int *)arg;
    int thr_2_ID = *pnum;
    sem_post(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain);
    while (true)
    {
        sem_wait(&sthr2[thr_2_ID]);
        sem_wait(&s12);
        string readVal = q.qPop();
        printString(readVal + ", THR2 "+ to_string(thr_2_ID));

        if (thr_2_ID==0)
            sem_post(&sthr2[1]); 
        else
            sem_post(&sthr2[0]); 
        sem_post(&s21);
    }
}

void *thread3(void* arg){
    sem_wait(&idInitializationSemMainToThread);
    int *pnum = (int *)arg;
    int thr_3_ID = *pnum;
    sem_post(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain);

    while (true)
    {
        sem_wait(&sthr3[thr_3_ID]);
        sem_wait(&s13);
        string readVal = q.qPop();
        printString(readVal + " THR3 " + to_string(thr_3_ID));
        if (thr_3_ID == 0)
             sem_post(&sthr3[1]);
        else
            sem_post(&sthr3[0]);  

        sem_post(&s31);
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thr1[THR1NUM], thr2[THR2NUM], thr3[THR3NUM];

    sem_init(&s12, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s13, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s31, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&s21, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&printSem, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&sthr1, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++)
        sem_init(&sthr2[i], 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2;i++)
        sem_init(&sthr3[i], 0, 0);
    sem_init(&idInitializationSemMainToThread, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain, 0, 0);

    int *pnum =(int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

    for (int j = 0; j < THR2NUM;j++){
        *pnum = j;
        pthread_create(&thr2[j], NULL, thread2, (void *)pnum);
        sem_post(&idInitializationSemMainToThread);
         printString("thr2 "+to_string(j)+ " created");
        sem_wait(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain);
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < THR3NUM;k++){
        *pnum = k;
        pthread_create(&thr3[k], NULL, thread3,(void *) pnum);
        sem_post(&idInitializationSemMainToThread);
        printString("thr3 "+to_string(k)+ " created");
        sem_wait(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < THR1NUM;i++){
        *pnum = i;
        pthread_create(&thr1[i], NULL, thread1,(void *) pnum);
        sem_post(&idInitializationSemMainToThread);
        printString("thr1 "+to_string(i)+ " created");
        sem_wait(&idInitializationSemThreadToMain);
    }
    sem_post(&sthr2[0]);
    sem_post(&sthr3[0]);
    sem_post(&sthr1);

    for (int i = 0; i < THR1NUM;i++){
        pthread_join(thr1[i], NULL);
        printString("thr1 "+to_string(i)+ " joined");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < THR2NUM; i++){
        pthread_cancel(thr2[i]);
        printString("thr2 "+to_string(i)+ " exited");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < THR3NUM;i++){
        pthread_cancel(thr3[i]);
        printString("thr3 "+to_string(i)+ " exited");
        sem_post(&printSem);
    }



    sem_destroy(&s12);
    sem_destroy(&s21);
    sem_destroy(&s13);
    sem_destroy(&s31);
    sem_destroy(&sthr1);

    free(pnum);
}

// function to print strings atomically.
void printString(string str){
    sem_wait(&printSem);
    printf("%s\n", str.c_str());
    sem_post(&printSem);
}
```

Comment: What is not a healthy way to write program? Can you be more specific as to what is your actual problem?

Comment: First thing I'd suggest is to learn using C++ threads. They interact much better with C++ than POSIX threads. That said, the answer how to avoid globals is to simply pass context information to the thread functions, that's why they receive a void pointer.

Comment: SergeyA my problem is the variables I declare are global. This is not healthy because they are accessible to any function in the program even the ones that do not use those variables. My question is how to declare them locally and what is the right way to pass them to the threads?

Comment: Ulrich Eckhardt, I was trying to learn C that is why I used POSIX threads,  but I found some difficulties with it. That is why I moved to c++ I wanted my code as close as possible to C in order to learn it. Now for the answer that you provided, i see that the thread takes only one argument of the form void*, how do I pass more arguments to threads?

Comment: Ismael,  you can pass any structure via the void pointer.  In the receiving function you create a pointer to the desired type and cast the passed in void pointer (which actually points to some class or struct) to the correct type.  Then you can access any amount of data that is contained in the the class pointed to by the void pointer.

Comment: @ttemple This makes sense, thank you. I know what to do now